# Running Kafka how docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apache-kafka, dockerfile

if someone can help me with this, i would be very grateful, i have a docker image in which a kafka is displayed where i pretend to have 3 brokers and i would like that nothing more be created when the docker container is created, the script that i have to raise kafka will be executed, i have tried in many ways using CMD and ENTRYPOINT commands but i am not successful, the container is created for me but the script is not executed i have to enter the container to start it

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN apt-get install -y wget \
    && wget http://apache.rediris.es/kafka/2.4.0/kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz \
    && tar -xzf kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz \
    && rm -R kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz


#WORKDIR /home

RUN chmod +x /kafka_2.12-2.4.0

### COPY ###

COPY server-1.properties /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/

COPY server-2.properties /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/


#ADD runzk-kf.sh .

COPY runzk-kf.sh /usr/local/bin/runzk-kf.sh

#COPY runzk-kf.sh .
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/runzk-kf.sh

EXPOSE 2181

EXPOSE 9092

EXPOSE 9093

EXPOSE 9094

CMD ./bin/bash
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/sh
# turn on bash's job control

set -m

### RUN Zookeper

./kafka_2.12-2.4.0/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/zookeeper.properties &

### RUN Kafka brokers ###

./kafka_2.12-2.4.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/server.properties &

./kafka_2.12-2.4.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/server-1.properties &

./kafka_2.12-2.4.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/server-2.properties &
```

[View all code](https://github.com/MartinPlay01/Kafka/tree/2.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but please don't do this.

1. Docker images should be one service, not 4. Use Compose or MiniKube + Helm Charts to orchestrate multiple.
2. It's not clear what property files you changed for that to work properly.
3. JDK 8 is end of life, use 11 or 13, which Kafka supports.
4. Just use existing Docker images. If you want something minimal, personally I use `bitnami/kafka`. If you want something more fully featured, take a look [over  at Confluent's repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml) on running 3 Brokers via Docker Compose.